# How to handle LDAP password containing angle brackets in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 application that uses LDAP for authentication of internal users.

I have just come across a scenario in which a user has angle brackets in their password, for example `My<Special>Password`, which is a valid password in LDAP.  When the user tries to log in to the application the following exception is thrown:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
```

which is what I would expect, but not what I want in this case.

I know I could decorate the `LogOn` method with `[ValidateInput(false)]` but my application also allows external users to register with a password of their own choosing and so I would still like to catch any 'potentially dangerous' form fields.

Is there a more elegant solution to using the `[ValidateInput(false)]` attribute combined with writing custom code to check a user's password?

Comment: Yes, I know StackOverflow does not recommend using tags in the title.  However, without the MVC in the title, I did a search for "MVC LDAP password angle brackets", and no results were returned.  Also, with regards to titles StackOverflow do recommend to "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem"

Comment: Your title is perfectly fine. Take a look [at this meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/215013) for examples of tags in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't post that you're using a model. But if you are using a model or could convert to a simple model to allow for model binding, you could probably decorate the password property with [`[AllowHtml]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) to skip validation on that property.

As an alternative, you maybe able to use `Request.Unvalidated().Form["Password"]` which would give you access to the unvalidated form data.

Comment: I am using a model, so I could use the decoration. And rather embarrassingly I've used that attribute elsewhere