# Issue with HTML symbols in MVC Password Inputs (.NET Bug??)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Had a user include a "<" in their password. This of course isn't allowed and was causing a Post-Back crash. What threw me was "<" was allowed in other input boxes on my site.

Traced the problem down to the fact that it was because the Password box was being treated like a Password box using DataType.Password. If I commented out that DataType attribute, it works (but of course displays the password on the screen as I'm typing)

Doing some research and Testing, I found 2 possible solutions but I can't tell the difference between the two other than Method # 2 breaks the UI style and looks ugly

Method #1 ... Modify the Model...

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
[AllowHtml]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string UserPassword { get; set; }

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserPassword ....
```

This option makes me nervous because I really don't want to allow HTML code in any of my inputs.

Method #2 ... Modify the View

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "Password")]
public string UserPassword { get; set; }

@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.UserPassword ....
```

This makes me nervous because I'm relying on any views that display this model to have been done correctly and not present the password in plain text.

So my questions are:

1. Why does MVC\Razr seem to handle HTML just fine for a normal text box but chokes when you flag it as a Password DataType?
2. Which of the two methods is the Best practices and safest? (Is their a 3rd option?)

Thanks

Comment: 3. Why are you storing passwords in plain text? That should be your #1 priority fixing. After fixing that, using `[AllowHtml]` becomes a non-issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300213/

Comment: Nope.. passwords are not in plain text. Even if they were, the Error happens during the MVC binding before I can even get the password to store. 

My question was why does and Editfor allow HTML, but doesn't with DataType.Password. as well is which is the "Best Practice" the "allowhtml" tag OR the .PasswordFor helping in the view instead.